# How to execute a Spring Batch job from a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have two spring apps. First one is a Spring Boot (app **A**) and the other is a standalone Spring Batch (app **B**) app.

Usually, I am using a script to execute the Spring Batch (app **B**) jar and in the main method, I will write the jobs that I want to run.

```
 ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(RacerBatchApp.class, args);
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    try {
        jobLauncher.run((Job) context.getBean("JOB NAME -> XXX"), new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("job.key", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters());
    } catch (BeansException | JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have a new requirement to launch a specific job in app **B** via app **A**.  Basically app **A** Spring Boot will execute the standalone app **B** jar and job name **XXX** (hope I am clear)

Also, I don’t want to add Spring Batch dependence to the Spring Boot app.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the job name as an argument to appA, and use it in the `main` method to get the job by name from the application context:

```
java -jar appA.jar job.name=myJob
```

Then in the main method:

```
String jobName = ..; // get job.name from application arguments;
Job job = context.getBean(jobName, Job.class);
// run the job
...
```

That said, I would make appB a Boot Batch app and just run:

```
java -jar appB.jar --spring.batch.job.names=myJob
```